# CGAffineTransform properties in different animation blocks

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

My goal is to transform a UIView in an animation. The problem is that the horizontal translation needs to be animated using a spring/bounce animation while the vertical translation needs to be animated without it.

The following code won't work because the second transform will replace the first but I wanted to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Is it possible to solve this without animating the views frame directly?

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.01, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
        someView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, 0)
}) { (completed) -> Void in

}

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        someView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make `someView` a child of another view that gets the second transformation applied.

```
   UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.01, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.someView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, 0)
        }) { (completed) -> Void in


    }
    let someOtherView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame);
    self.view.addSubview(someOtherView);
    someOtherView.addSubview(someView);
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.01, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
        someOtherView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100)
        }) { (completed) -> Void in

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I have no knowledge or control over the view hirarchy in this case to I can only assume a single UIView